# commerce product display news

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a problem that I am not sure how to address. I am using commerce guys and Drupal 7. I have some products around 200. But each one will have updates or news of what it is going on with them. How could I accomplish this so each product will display its news. For instance

Product Name 
Description  
Origin

**PRODUCT NEWS**

Month 1 
lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Month 2  
lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Month 3  
lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

**view all product news**

The first part is easily done with view mode but I have no clue what it is the best way to integrate news to a product display. I have searching in commerce guys and display suite but still don't have an idea. Do you have any advice, experience or module or how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would establish a Product News content type, and equip it with an Entity Reference field, whereby you could link the news to a product sku or product display - your choice. Then, in the product display you could introduce a [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) which would gather the related news through a View criteria that you will set up). The view would have to accept an argument (product sku or product display node id - depending on what the news should refer to).

Answer (score 2):

A similar way would be to use Entity Views Attachment ([EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva)) along with a Product News content and utilize the tagging on the product to obtain a related news view